# Nested Set Model for graph like structures

Tags: mysql, graph, tree, rdbms

I have a hierarchical data in MySQL. And this is not exactly a tree structure but more of a graph. Any child could have any number of parents. In such cases how do I get access to a node's all children without missing any? Can I use Nested Set Model in anyway possible??

Comment: Can you post some code showing what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

A graph is a set of nodes and a set of edges. Nodes can be represented in a normal table and edges can be represented in the following way.

```
|id|node_1|node_2|
| 1|  1234|  1235|
| 2|  1234|  1236|
| 3|  1236|  1237|
| 4|  1237|  1238|
```

Querying for all the parents of node `1234` would simply be.

```
SELECT node_2 FROM edges WHERE node_1 = 1234
```

Traversing graphs in a relational databases however can be cumbersome and inefficient and if your dataset is moderate to large it can make sense to look at a [graph database as an alternative](https://neo4j.com/developer/graph-db-vs-rdbms/).